# Why doesn't work the maximize and reduce?

Tags: equation-solving

**Alguien puede ayudarme por favor?**
He estado tratando de resolver y hallar en base a las funciones maximizar y reducir, la expresion de P y sus restricciones, pero no he podido obtener.

```
Maximize[{(p (\[Epsilon] \[Mu] - Log[k/(k - p)]))/(\[Epsilon] \[Lambda]d) == 0, k > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 0 && \[Lambda]d > 0 && \[Mu] > 0 && \[Lambda]d > 0}, p]

Reduce[-(p/((k - p) \[Epsilon] \[Lambda]d)) + (\[Epsilon] \[Mu] - Log[k/(k - p)])/(\[Epsilon] \[Lambda]d) == 0 && p < k && k > 0 && \[Epsilon] > 0 && \[Lambda]d > 0 && \[Mu] > 0, {p}]
```

Comment: ¿Qué expresión necesitas maximizar? El primer parámetro de la `List`(`{ }`) en `Maximize` debería ser una función, no una ecuación / restricción. (Google Translate)

Comment: I need to maximize the expression  (p (\[Epsilon] \[Mu] - Log[k/(k - p)]))/(\[Epsilon] \[Lambda]d) and find the "p" that maximizes this expression

Comment: I think this maximization cannot be symbolically acquired... Do you have numeric values for these parameters, or maybe you could explain the physical intuition behind the math?